# Action Keys Mode on Gigabyte Bios

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fn-key

How can I disable fn key/action key mode in my desktop pc?

for some reason it got enabled and is giving me trouble.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Have you tried FN+Numlock?

Comment: I'm on Win 8.1, as said i'm on a desktop pc and no Fn key is present on my keyboard. Pressing Numlock normally turns volume up and pressing space turns it down.